# Can't retrieve data from EF database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple application which should display the elements of a list, but it returns an empty array when debugging. I need this elements to be displayed dinamically. I'm wondering if the program is not working because of the following code...

StoreController.cs

```
using GetMed.Models;

namespace GetMed.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        GetMedEntities storeDB = new GetMedEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Store/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var categories = storeDB.Categories.ToList();

            return View(categories);
        }
    }
}
```

SampleData.cs:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace GetMed.Models
{
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<GetMedEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(GetMedEntities context)
        {
            var categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category { Name = "Infections" },
                new Category { Name = "Antibiotics" },
                new Category { Name = "Vitamins" },
                new Category { Name = "Cosmetics" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

GetMedEntities.cs

```
namespace GetMed.Models
{
    public class GetMedEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Index.cs:

```
@model IEnumerable<GetMed.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h3>Browse Categories</h3>
<p>Select from @Model.Count() categories:</p>
<ul>
    @foreach (var category in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(category.Name, "Browse", new { category = category.Name })</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your database, you will notice that there is no data in it. Look at your `Seed` method: what do you expect it to do?

After creating your data you have two more steps to do:

1. Adding it to a collection tracked by your `DbContext`
2. Saving it to the database

This results in these extra lines:

```
context.Categories.AddRange(categories);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Never initialize EF context gloablly, once it gonna hit you hard, believe me
2. When adding records to DB via EF you have to call

   ```
   using (var context = new GetMedEntities)
   {
       // YOUR ADD ROUTINE GOES HERE

       context.SaveChanges();
   }
   ```

**UPDATE**

Change your class `SampleData`

```
    public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<GetMedEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(GetMedEntities context)
        {
//I STRICTLY RECOMMEND NOT TO PROVIDE CONTEXT AS A METHOD PARAMETER 
//YOU HAVE TO WRITE PROPER DB LAYER TO DO SO

            context.Categories.AddRange( new List<Category>()
            {
                new Category { Name = "Infections" },
                new Category { Name = "Antibiotics" },
                new Category { Name = "Vitamins" },
                new Category { Name = "Cosmetics" }
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

But the simple solution is the following:

```
public class SampleData 
{
  public void SeedSampleData() 
  {
    var context = new GedMedEntities();
    context.Categories.AddRange( new List<Category>()
    {
      new Category { Name = "Infections" },
      new Category { Name = "Antibiotics" },
      new Category { Name = "Vitamins" },
      new Category { Name = "Cosmetics" }
    });
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this doesn't works

Comment: What you see in `categories` when placing break marker on `return View(categories);` line ? is it full ?

Comment: problem is quite clear, will provide you solution in a sec

Comment: I forgot to mention...I'm using this tutorial as reference : http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

Comment: Check it and make it simple

Comment: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GetMed.Models.Category>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GetMed.Models.Category>' could be found

Comment: And there is another problem...I need to store the List<Category> in a variable for using it in another List

Comment: then initialize list and insert each element with 
`foreach (var elem in yourList) 
{
context.Categories.Add(elem);
}`

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Visual-2013-Step-Developer/dp/073568183X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1440362896&sr=8-1&keywords=visual+c%23

Comment: It's a little more complicate than this because the list also has another elements...new Product { Title = "name", Category = categories.Single(p => p.Name == "name"), Price = 8.99M, Manufacturer = manufacturer.Single(m => m.Name == "name"), ProductImgUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" }.